# Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: socket

Tags: sockets, jsf, primefaces, atmosphere

Error msg when my xhtml page loads, pointing to the following line in my xhtml:

> " Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui,
>   but no tag was defined for name: socket"

The line in my xhtml:
(after the h:form is closed)

```
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/counter" />
```

(I followed carefully the great tutorial here: http://blog.eisele.net/2012/09/primefaces-push-with-atmosphere-on.html)

Where should I look to debug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first sentence of the blog which you linked there says:

> *PrimeFaces 3.4 came out three days ago. Beside the usual awesomeness of new and updated components it also includes the new PrimeFaces Push framework.*

So, it's only available since PrimeFaces 3.4. The error message which you got suggests that you haven't [upgraded](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html) to 3.4 yet, or that the upgrade itself wasn't done properly (e.g. the older PrimeFaces version wasn't been removed at all).

Comment: I was already on 3.4 but indeed had to change in Maven to 3.4.1, thx a ton! (just started with Maven yesterday, still getting used to it)